# How to exclude Multiple folders with the EXTRA_ARGS variable?

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

With the current syntax of bitbucket's EXTRA_ARGS variable one directory is excluded from deployment like this:

`EXTRA_ARGS: '--exclude=YOUR_DESIRE_FOLDER_PATH/*'`

([Bitbucket Pipeline - how to exclude files or folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57128087/bitbucket-pipeline-how-to-exclude-files-or-folders))

But how to exclude multiple directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that not every pipe has a support for `--exclude` option, as some pipes are just wrappers around the cli tools, like rsync or sftp. However, if you use the [rsync-deploy](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/rsync-deploy) pipe, you should be able to use multiple `--exclude` options:

```
script:
  - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.3.2
    variables:
      USER: 'ec2-user'
      SERVER: '127.0.0.1'
      REMOTE_PATH: '/var/www/build/'
      LOCAL_PATH: 'build'
      DEBUG: 'true'
      EXTRA_ARGS: '--exclude=*.txt --exclude=src/*'
```